# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' problem

Tags: python, ios

hello guys i have a problem with my code this isn't running:

```
from napalm import get_network_driver


driver = get_network_driver('ios')
device = driver('192.168.112.130', 'abc', '123')
device.open()


device.load_merge_candidate(filename='IOSConfig.txt')
print(device.compare_config())

if len(device.compare_config()) > 0:
    choice = input('\nWould you like commit these changes? [y/n]: ')
    if choice == 'y':
        print('Committing ...')
        device.commit_config()
    else:
        print('Discarding ...')
        device.discard_config()
else:
    print('No difference')

# close the session with the device.
device.close()
print('Done.')
```

and the error is:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a traceback for your error. At the moment, it is impossible for us to even guess at the problem.

Comment: [mcve] and full matching traceback please - if you hope to get any help at least...

Answer (score 0):

Script is okay , but you need to make sure your cisco device must have real flash and should be enable with SCP server. In Simulation sometime cisco image doesn't have flash.

Try below with router which have flash. Make sure you have user credentials in place already.
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authorization exec default local
!
ip scp server enable
!
archive
path flash0:

Script will do below task so your router
CMD: 'terminal width 511' 19:23:52 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021
CMD: 'terminal length 0' 19:23:52 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021
CMD: 'dir' 19:23:52 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021
CMD: 'dir flash0:' 19:23:52 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021
CMD: 'dir flash0:/merge_config.txt' 19:23:53 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021
CMD: 'verify /md5 flash0:/merge_config.txt' 19:23:53 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021
CMD: 'show archive config incremental-diffs flash0:/merge_config.txt ignorecase' 19:23:53 UTC Fri Sep 3 2021

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.